# How to use Python Scrapy if CSS or XPATH selectors don't work?

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from this site using scrapy shell.

```
    https://api.simon.com/v1.2/tenant?mallId=1345&key=40A6F8C3-3678-410D-86A5-BAEE2804C8F2&lw=true
```

My goal is to extract all the tenant information.

However, I'm having difficulties as it seems that both my CSS and XML selectors aren't working, or at least they're not returning any information.  The website says that it's an XML file without any style information associated with it.  I'm not sure what that means.

I've narrowed down the problem and am now just trying to return information on a single tenant/store but I still can't seem to figure it out.  Here are some of the selectors that I've tried

```
    response.xpath('//*[@id="collapsible2"]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/text()').extract() 
    response.css("#collapsible2 > div.expanded > div:nth-child(1) > span.html-tag::text").extract()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the content of that XML code? There is no attribute 'collapsible2' in it.

Comment: I'm not sure what "collapsible2" is, so no.

Comment: You can only use tag names, attributes and values which exist in the code of that page. Open the URL in a browser and then look where the desired content is located.

Comment: Isn't the content located on that URL? Here is the original URL that I want to scrape from http://www.simon.com/mall/abq-uptown/stores. I only got to the URL above by accessing the ajax calls from the original site.

Comment: I am afraid scrapy is not suitable for this site. However, the simon.com has a sitemap http://www.simon.com/sitemap.xml that contains a sitemap index with two entries. You can try to process URLs included in them.

Comment: If scrapy won't work, do you know of any other methods to scrape this information?